# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 on usb with persistant data

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, live-usb

I have a 32 gb usb and i am using windows as my daily driver. in my home there are 2laptops and 0 desptops
one of them died which is my daily driver and i use linux on it and the windows one is my dads so i cant do dual boot as it got only 500 gig storage so i want to install ubuntu 20.04 on my usb to daily driver it . I am a linux user and fan but i am just learning about it .

---

Note Please dont tell the rufus or other program for persistant boot because it wont work very god with me i tried that.

---

If i can install ubuntu on usb just like hardisk install so please tell me i got to know that ubntu's
community is very good so please tell me this is my first question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Ubuntu in a USB stick and run it as my learning machine? Will it run as a normal Ubuntu without difference?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267370/can-i-install-ubuntu-in-a-usb-stick-and-run-it-as-my-learning-machine-will-it-r). If you need not encrypt the Ubuntu system, there is an easy alternative: extract and clone from a compressed image file according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539&p=13974203#post13974203)

Comment: The question is unclear: *Installing* creates a full, persistent Ubuntu system, regardless of the storage device. Many folks *install* full Ubuntu to a USB stick. *Creating a LiveUSB installer with persistence* is not installing Ubuntu; it's merely making the installer's image bootable, with the additional tweak of making the "Try Ubuntu" environment persistent.

Comment: There are a few different ways to make a full install of UBUNTU to USB. I have tested three of the methods on this page and am testing the fourth right now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to a Windows computer, you can download Rufus [here](https://rufus.ie/). Insert your USB drive into your Windows PC, open the Rufus, choosing your USB drive and the 20.04 ISO file which you'll need to download first. A "persistent partition size" option should appear. Choose how much space to allocate and create your drive.

Edit: I failed to notice that the original question asked not to use Rufus. In that case, one could either use another USB creation tool that supports persistence on Windows, or otherwise on Linux use mkusb. If the Rufus approach fails for you again, please let me know and I'll update the answer with either another Windows USB tool or the mkusb tool instructions. If you don't want to use persistent boot software period, I'm sure there's still a way to do this but it would be beyond me.

Comment: Okay i will try it again

Comment: Pardon, I didn't notice that you specifically didn't want to use Rufus. If I recall correctly, I read somewhere that Linux Live USB Creator didn't work with later versions of Ubuntu, but I don't know for sure. If you want to create a persistent live USB drive from a Linux machine, I can give a link to a tutorial that does just that.