# Can I install Ubuntu 20 on a portable USB drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, 20.04, hard-drive

Can Ubuntu 20.04 be fully installed on a USB drive or removable drive? I want to install a fully functional Ubuntu 20 Operating System onto either a USB Thumb drive or a USB removable Hard Drive because I cannot install it directly onto the computers internal HD the RSD configuration wont allow it. Can this be done? If so how? What specific drive would it require?  Also would it boot on most computers by booting from USB using the F12 option.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Yes, you can. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267370/can-i-install-ubuntu-in-a-usb-stick-and-run-it-as-my-learning-machine-will-it-r/1267376#1267376) and links from it.

Comment: For a few methods for Full install that work with both BIOS and UEFI boot, that answer yes to all your questions, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step the method **Install Ubuntu from a Pre-built Image File**. is the easiest.