# Want to install ubuntu to external HDD and use on the PC where I have Windows 10 running (without disturbing original window 10 boot loader)

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have a windows 10 desktop. Would like to install ubuntu to an external HDD and use it on same above computer. I know the steps to do that.

But with the steps I know, it modifies the bootloader so that Ubuntu comes as an option in the boot menu. And in any case I decided to stop using the ubuntu (that is unplug the external HDD where ubuntu is installed),the modified boot loader still shows up.

I would like to know if I could set it up such a way that, whenever I unplug the external HDD, PC just boots windows (As if it didn't know ubuntu never existed).

Thanks

Comment: You can have the bootloader on the external drive which means no menu will appear on your PC as it contains only windows and thus will boot only windows (if external drive is connected or not). With this method, to boot the external drive (with Ubuntu) you'll need to tell the firmware of your box to boot the external drive (usually the pressing of a key, dictated by you box firmware) which will cause the Ubuntu system to boot & run.  *You gave no specifics on Ubuntu, if server, desktop, specialist, what release etc, so this is generic comment only*

Comment: If UEFI system, you have to partition in advance & use gpt partitioning. And include the ESP - efi system partition. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer defaults to install grub bootloader to  first drive's ESP, usually your internal drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267370/can-i-install-ubuntu-in-a-usb-stick-and-run-it-as-my-learning-machine-will-it-r/1267376#1267376 & Manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379